# Ubuntu 16.04 - Blank window appears when java application are launched

Tags: 16.04, java

A blank window appears when java applications like jedit,intellij are launched.
I have java openjdk version "1.8.0_131"
Tried various solutions like:
1) Setting export _JAVA_AWT_WM_NONREPARENTING=1
2) wmname LG3D  and wmname compiz.

None of the above are working :(
Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution to my issue.Seems like apps were getting launched in seperate window.

To Fix : 
Click on top left ubuntu icon and type Displays.
Goto Displays settings.
Select Built-in display -> OFF

It worked for me after this change.